# date field type displays as a string

Tags: channel-entries, date, fieldtype

I'm using a date field type to display the date of an upcoming event, but when its rendered it displays as a string of numbers.  For example, one date displays as "1356393654".  I'm not using any plug-ins, and I've already set the date formatting, which doesn't seem to have an effect.  Any ideas?

```
    <ul class="upcoming-events>
        <li class="section-post">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="home" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" sort="asc"}
            <h3><img src="{site_url}/images/interface/noun_project_8151.svg" width="18" alt="calendar"> {title}</h3>
            <h5>{event_date format=%D, %F %d, %Y}</h5>
            <p>{event_details}</p>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I guess your forgot the '' between your format date => {event_date format='%D, %F %d, %Y'}

Comment: Simon, you ought to add that as an answer instead of a comment, as you are correct.

Comment: I really don't know If I'm correct or not. I'll put it if it fix the problem.

Comment: wow...that was dumb.  thank you Simon!  Sometimes you just get lost in the code and can't see what should be REALLY obvious.  thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the '' in your  tag :

```
<h5>{event_date format=%D, %F %d, %Y}</h5>
```

Correct :

```
<h5>{event_date format='%D, %F %d, %Y'}</h5>
```